# Word for something that you sold everything to buy?

Tags: word-choice

Is there a word or phrase that means selling everything you own, to your name, etc., to buy one particular thing?

Comment: There's no word for it as far as I know, but its 'the pearl of great price' after the usual section heading in the Bible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He **beggered** himself buying that Porsche.

[Academic Law dictionary](http://law.academic.ru/21885/beggared):

> Beggared — Beggar Beg gar, v. t. [imp. & p. p. {Beggared}; p. pr. & vb. n. {Beggaring}.] 1. To reduce to beggary; to impoverish; as, he had beggared himself. Milton. [1913 Webster] 2. To cause to seem very poor and inadequate. [1913 Webster] It beggared all …

Comment: +1 for a good find. However, it is not the "he" but the "thing" that we need a word for. So this is not an answer after all.

Answer (score -1):

Giving up all your property - perhaps for religious reasons - is called 'repudiating' your property, although that doesn't cover the 'buying something else with the money' part of the meaning that you're looking for.

> repudiate, *verb*
>
> 1. trans. 
>    a. To cast off, disown (a person or thing previously claimed as one's own or associated with oneself).

["repudiate, v." OED Online. Oxford University Press, December 2014. Web. 27 January 2015.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/163175)

> Ubertino asserted that Christ and the Apostles, though they had **repudiated all property** as private persons, made use of goods and money for necessaries and alms as ministers of religion.

[Wikipedia: Ubertino of Casale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubertino_of_Casale)